# How import CardsLib lib into eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, cardslib

CardLib have the following link : [library](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib)

I have problem when I try to import in Eclipse.

Segui also this link: [Link de Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oy5OXOjLNHA)

But without any good result

I hope you can help me or some other library to use it.

Thank You

Comment: download the source and resource files, merge with your source files and then change R imports in each class. and also why do you want to import in eclipse?. Google has now dropped support for it.

Answer (score 1):

Today you should use the official IDE Android Studio for Android Dev.

This library has all its modules in gradle as aar, and you can easily add this dependency to your project.

However, You can find [here](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/BUILD.md#reference-this-project-as-a-library-in-eclipse) all the info to build the library in Eclipse.

Warning:

- this library has many modules as described [here](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/BUILD.md#including-in-your-project-with-gradle):
- you have to build all modules you need
- you have to import in your workspace, the support libraries (support-v4, annotation, recycler-view, cardView)